# Undifined variable when trying to fill variable with onChange

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux, react-redux

I want to onChange of input type fill variable(I need it for name of city in api). But onChange it constantly is calling "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleCityName' of undefined" on this line

```
<input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={this.handleCityName.bind(this)}/>
```

I'm trying to transfer app to redux.

This is the rest of code

Form_container.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
        import SearchBar from '../components/SearchBar';
        import {connect} from "react-redux"
        import {updateInfo} from "../actions/weather-apiActions";
        import {handleCityName} from "../actions/weather-apiActions";


        @connect((store) => {
            return {
                cityName: store.cityName.cityName,
                nameOfCity:store.nameOfCity.nameOfCity,
                weatherDescription:store.weatherDescription.weatherDescription,
                windSpeed:store.windSpeed.windSpeed,
                temperature:store.temperature.temperature,
                maxTemperature:store.maxTemperature.maxTemperature,
                minTemperature:store.minTemperature.minTemperature,
            }
        })

        class FormContainer extends Component {

            handleFormSubmit(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                this.props.dispatch(updateInfo());
            }

            handleCityName(value){
                this.props.dispatch(handleCityName(value));
            }


            render() {
                return (
                    <div>
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleFormSubmit.bind(this)}>
                        <label>{this.props.label}</label>
                        <SearchBar
                            name="CityName"
                            type="text"
                            value={this.props.cityName}
                            placeholder="search"
                            onChange={this.cityName.bind(this)}
                        />

                        <button type="submit" className="" value='Submit' placeholder="Search">Search</button>
                    </form>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        }

        export {FormContainer};
```

Searchbar.js

```
import React from 'react';

    const SearchBar = (props) => (
        <div>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={this.handleCityName.bind(this)}/>
        </div>
    );
    export default SearchBar;
```

Action

```
export function handleCityName(value) {
return {
    type:"HANDLE_CITY_NAME",
    results:{
        cityName: value,
    }
  }
}
```

Reducer

```
 export default function reducer(state={
    cityName: "",
}, action) {
    switch (action.type){
        case "HANDLE_CITY_NAME": {
            return {...state,
                cityName: action.value,
            }
        }
    }

    return state;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Change your function handleCityName.

```
handleCityName(e){
    let value = e.target.value;
    this.props.dispatch(handleCityName(value));
}
```

2.Send this function to SearchBar with props.

```
<SearchBar
    name="CityName"
    type="text"
    value={this.props.cityName}
    placeholder="search"
    onChange={this.handleCityName.bind(this)}
/>
```

3.Call it with onChange

```
const SearchBar = (props) => (
        <div>
            <label>{props.label}</label>
            <input name={props.name} type={props.inputType} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} onChange={(e) => props.handleCityName(e)}/>
        </div>
    );
```

Check console log on this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/71191/).
But i don't think it's a good idea to dispatch action with input onChange.

Comment: what would you recommend how to write it because I'm still to wrap my head how to use redux correctly

Comment: You should recive somewhere your values frome input and kept it on some variable. And on submit call action. 

In your variant you will call action after writing one latter. 

For example word Andrew will call yor action handleCityName 6 time(6 latters), this will update state 6 times and 6 times re-render your component